# Convert flat JSON to nested JSON with PHP

Tags: php, json, nested

I have a JSON file with a single array and all elements in the same level.
Each of the entries has a "level" attribute between 1 and 4.
I want to have a nested array in the end which has all level 4 inside the level 3, all level 3 inside the level 2, all level 2 inside the level 1.

The JSON example is like this:

> [{"text e":"Test","id":1073,"level":1,"chapter":"1"}, {"text e":"Test
> 2","id":1073,"level":2,"chapter":"1.1"}, {"text e":"Test
> 3","id":1063,"level":2,"chapter":"1.2"}, {"text e":"Test
> 4","id":1031,"level":3,"chapter":"1.2.1"}, {"text e":"Test
> 5","id":1334,"level":4,"chapter":"1.2.1.1"}, {"text e":"Test
> 6","id":1127,"level":2,"chapter":"1.3"}, {"text e":"Test
> 7","id":1092,"level":2,"chapter":"1.4"}, {"text e":"Test
> 8","id":1012,"level":1,"chapter":"2"}]

```
<?php
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents("menuitems.json"), true);
$newArr = array();
$keyLevel1 = 0;
$keyLevel2 = 0;
$keyLevel3 = 0;
$keyLevel4 = 0;
foreach ($json as $key => $item) {
    if ($item['level'] == 1) {
        $newArr[$keyLevel1] = $item;
        $keyLevel1 = $keyLevel1 + 1;
        $keyLevel2 = 0;
        $keyLevel3 = 0;
        $keyLevel4 = 0;
    } else if ($item['level'] == 2) {
        $newArr[$keyLevel1][$keyLevel2] = $item;
        $keyLevel2 = $keyLevel2 + 1;
        $keyLevel3 = 0;
        $keyLevel4 = 0;
    } else if ($item['level'] == 3) {
        $newArr[$keyLevel1][$keyLevel2][$keyLevel3] = $item;
        $keyLevel3 = $keyLevel3 + 1;
        $keyLevel4 = 0;
    } else if ($item['level'] == 4) {
        $newArr[$keyLevel1][$keyLevel2][$keyLevel3][$keyLevel4] = $item;
        $keyLevel4 = $keyLevel4 + 1;
    }
}
echo json_encode($newArr);
?>
```

This code seems to work for the first level but the level 2 of the last item are written in the last object and they're not nesting.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a classic off-by-one error.  You're incrementing all of the keyLevel variables at the wrong time.  The simplest fix might be to always (re-)initialize them all to -1, and then increment *before* using, for instance, the first "if" would become:

```
$keyLevel1 = -1;
...

    if ($item['level'] == 1) {
        $keyLevel1 = $keyLevel1 + 1;
        $newArr[$keyLevel1] = $item;
        $keyLevel2 = -1;
        $keyLevel3 = -1;
        $keyLevel4 = -1;
    }
```

That way, $keyLevel1 will have the correct value when you process the subsequent level 2, 3, and 4 items.